# How to add a footer to a table in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, format

I have a table that is longer than one page. I have found the option to make the header of the table to be added to the second portion of the table after the page break. Is there a way to do the same thing with a footer on the table? I want to add a footer so that if my table was 1000 entries long (12 pages), that the first and last row of each page would be consistent; a header and footer for the table. If I edit the rest of the document (above the table) the table will shift up/down and I want to header and footer of the table to remain at the page breaks. Any ideas?

> PAGE BREAK

```
HEADER OF TABLE
TBL TBL TBL
TBL TBL TBL
TBL TBL TBL
TBL TBL TBL
FOOTER OF TABLE
```

> PAGE BREAK

```
HEADER OF TABLE
TBL TBL TBL
TBL TBL TBL
FOOTER OF TABLE

TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

> PAGE BREAK

Answer (score 3):

There's no option in Word to do it. The only way I know of is to put the table into its own section and use the page footers to mimic what you want. See the explanation [here](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T000415_Repeating_Rows_for_a_Table_Footer.html) for a rough explanation.